# Center is always a commutative subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be a ring.  The center of R is defined to be the set of all elements x ∈ R such that xr=rx for all r ∈ R. Prove that the center of R is always a commutative subring of R.

I understand how to prove tha the center of R is always a subring, but how do I show the commutative subring?

Comment: What are you having problems with, what have you already done?

Comment: I have started the problem with the subring test.  I am unsure how to show that the center of R is always commutative subring of R